# In the year 2016, in the year of 2016, of the year 2016?

Tags: prepositions, time

In the phrase,

> On Saturday the twenty-third day of April, in the year two thousand and sixteen.

Is it more correct to say

1. "***in*** the year two thousand and sixteen"

or

2. "*in* the year ***of*** two thousand and sixteen"

or

3. "***of*** the year two thousand and sixteen"

Comment: Here are a few  wording samples you may find helpful: https://www.google.it/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=wedding+invitation+sample+wording&oq=wedding+invitation+sample&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.2.0j0i22i30l2.2320.11281.0.12605.27.12.1.14.15.0.149.1307.1j10.11.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..1.26.1385.ggm8cdBQ65U#imgrc=_

Comment: Thank you but common invitation wording simply states "two thousand and sixteen." None of them spell out in full "in the year two thousand and sixteen." That's why I am unsure of the proper prepositions before the year.

Answer (score 1):

*2016* or *two thousand and sixteen* is the name of the year, so the word *year* is an adposition. Both *day in* and *day of* are ok, but *year of two thousand and sixteen* is wrong.

Comment: You mean No. 2 is wrong? Or No. 3? Please focus on what is being asked in the question and explain why it is wrong with supporting references or examples.

Comment: Only one of the sentences contains *year of two thousand and sixteen*, so it's clear which of the sentences I'm talking about.

Comment: The reason why I asked the question was it doesn't sound wrong to me. As I commented, you need to explain why it is wrong. Please expand your answer.